# How to prevent an iOS notification being removed from the Notification Center when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to prevent a remote notification in the Notification Center from being removed by the OS after it is tapped by the user? The tap invokes the app and didReceiveNotificationResponse() is called.  I am not using badges in the notifications.

Comment: No, I do no think you cannot control the Notification Center like that.

Answer (score 2):

Apple is not allowing to persist the notification once after you open it.

What’s next
You can create a local notification from data you get from push notification when user taps on it. I have not tried the implementation but it should work in your usecase.

User will not be knowing whether it is local or push notification.

Comment: Thanks Saranjith. I thought of the same thing but that would mean that the "same" notification animates again which would be weird.

Comment: Can you somehow place the local notification in the Notification Center without the notification 'toast' animation?

Comment: I don’t think the toast animation will visible to the user because app would be launching at that time.